# Encoding used for u"" literals

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

Consider the next example:

```
>>> s = u"баба"
>>> s
u'\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0'
>>> print s
áàáà
```

I'm using `cp1251` encoding within the idle, but it seems like the interpreter actually uses `latin1` to create unicode string:

```
>>> print s.encode('latin1')
баба
```

Why so? Is there spec for such behavior?

CPython, 2.7.

---

**Edit**

The code I was actually looking for is

```
>>> u'\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0' == u'\u00e1\u00e0\u00e1\u00e0'
True
```

Seems like when encoding unicode with `latin1` codec, all unicode points less that 256 are simply left as is thus resulting in bytes which I typed in before.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The question isn't "what encoding is used for Unicode string literals" (a meaningless question; encodings are input/output things, the internal representation is obviously something that can represent Unicode and that's all you need to know). The question you really want to know the answer to is "why is IDLE messing up my text encodings, and is it happening on input or output, and how do I get it to do what I want?"

Comment: How you are defining your encoding? see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for defining encoding in your source file. Please give your python version also.
According to http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html
the default encoding used will be ASCII. Versions of Python before 2.4 were Euro-centric and assumed Latin-1 as a default encoding for string literals

Comment: @kindall well, afaik, we do need to have encoding while creating a unicode object (since we need not bytes, but meaningful characters).  So why interpreter doesn't use my actual encoding to perform bytes->characters trans?

Comment: @Gagandeep cp1251 is simply my default OS encoding.

Comment: the interpreter has no way of knowing the encoding unless you provide it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you type a character such as `б` into the terminal, you see a `б`, but what is really inputted is a sequence of bytes.

Since your terminal encoding is `cp1251`, typing `баба` results in the sequence of bytes equal to the unicode `баба` encoded in `cp1251`:

```
In [219]: "баба".decode('utf-8').encode('cp1251')
Out[219]: '\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0'
```

(Note I use `utf-8` above because my terminal encoding is `utf-8`, not `cp1251`. For me, `"баба".decode('utf-8')` is just unicode for `баба`.)

Since typing `баба` results in the sequence of bytes `\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0`, when you type `u"баба"` into the terminal, Python receives `u'\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0'` instead. This is why you are seeing

```
>>> s
u'\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0'
```

This unicode happens to represent `áàáà`.

And when you type

```
>>> print s.encode('latin1')
```

the `latin1` encoding converts `u'\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0'` to `'\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0'`.
The terminal receives the sequence of bytes `'\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0'`, and decodes them with `cp1251`, thus printing `баба`:

```
In [222]: print('\xe1\xe0\xe1\xe0'.decode('cp1251'))
баба
```

Try:

```
>>> s = "баба"
```

(without the `u`) instead. Or,

```
>>> s = "баба".decode('cp1251')
```

to make `s` `unicode`. Or, use the verbose but very explicit (and ***terminal-encoding agnostic***):

```
>>> s = u'\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BE}\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A}\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BE}\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A}'
```

Or the short but less-readily comprehensible

```
>>> s = u'\u0431\u0430\u0431\u0430'
```